# Why can HTML only open one append?

Tags: javascript, html

I had a JS script and I'm putting this thing in:

```js
bot.on("login", async () => {
    var mbon = document.createElement("div");
    div.style.cursor = "pointer";
    div.style.padding = "10px 20px";
    div.style.borderRadius = "3px";
    div.style.color = "rgb(7, 6, 6)";
    div.style.font = "normal 20px/normal Arial Black, Gadget, sans-serif"
    div.style.position = "absolute"
    div.style.top = "450px"
    div.style.left = "200px"
    div.innerHTML = `According to ${accb} The Bot Is Online`;
    document.body.append(mbon);
})
```

And:

```js
client.on("ready", async () => {
    var dbon = document.createElement("div");
    div.style.cursor = "pointer";
    div.style.padding = "10px 20px";
    div.style.borderRadius = "3px";
    div.style.color = "rgb(7, 6, 6)";
    div.style.font = "normal 20px/normal Arial Black, Gadget, sans-serif"
    div.style.position = "absolute"
    div.style.top = "400px"
    div.style.left = "200px"
    div.innerHTML = `Online Loggined as ${client.user.tag}. `;
    document.body.append(dbon);
})
```

The problem is, it can only show 1 div, for example = if `bot.on` appear then `client.on` appear the `bot.on` div will disappear again.

Comment: Currently you're appending only a single element, how are you expecting to see more than that single element?  also, what's the logic behind creating the element into `dbon` variable, then set properties of the element stored in `div` variable, and then append the empty element from `dbon` ..?

Comment: umm what do you mean i didnt understand

Comment: instead of doing ``div.style`` you should try ``dbon.style``

Comment: `document.body.append(dbon);` appends only a single element. Are you expecting `client.on("ready" ...)` to fire multiple times?

Comment: okay ill try to do that

Comment: Felix its working Thanks :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't referencing to the `mbon` and `dbon` variables, you're changing an unknown variable `div`. So your code should look like this:

```
bot.on("login", async () => {
    var mbon = document.createElement("div");
    mbon.style.cursor = "pointer";
    mbon.style.padding = "10px 20px";
    mbon.style.borderRadius = "3px";
    mbon.style.color = "rgb(7, 6, 6)";
    mbon.style.font = "normal 20px/normal Arial Black, Gadget, sans-serif"
    mbon.style.position = "absolute"
    mbon.style.top = "450px"
    mbon.style.left = "200px"
    mbon.innerHTML = `According to ${accb} The Bot Is Online`;
    document.body.append(mbon);
  })
```

Same goes for the second part of your code, just replace the `mbon` with `dbon`

Comment: @FarrelAthaillah If this solves your problem, please mark this answer as accepted by clicking the grey checkmark underneath the voting buttons. Please also see [the relevant page in the help centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)